# RewriteRule matches regular expression but isn't forwarding

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal

I'm "simply" trying to transform the URLS like

[AWEBSITE]/bgh/articles/10/08/2009/left-4-dead-2-scavenge-mode-announced

to

[AWEBSITE]/bgh/left-4-dead-2-scavenge-mode-announced

The regular expression matches properly (as tested using http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html), but nothing is happening. I've tried a similar rule, using RedirectMatch 301 instead:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/bgh/articles/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})/([^/]+)$ /bgh/$4?
```

And the URL transforms correctly, but leaves a "?" at the end. If I remove the question mark from that line, it transforms the URL correctly, but re-appends a query string on the end. Here's what I'm working with in .htaccess:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php53 .php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^bgh/articles/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})/(.*)$ bgh/$4

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^awebsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.awebsite\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.awebsite\.com\/bgh"

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html
```

Also, I'm using Drupal and what seems to be an older version of Apache (the QSD flag breaks my .htaccess, for example). I'm pulling my hair out and I hope that there's something really simple that I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php53 .php
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^bgh/articles/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})/(.*)$ bgh/$4? [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?awebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.awebsite.com/bgh [L,R]
```

Comment: That certainly looks cleaner, but unfortunately it still doesn't transform the URL at all. What are your thoughts about what I was doing wrong? It might help me keep looking for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Apache httpd 2.4, you can add the [QSD] tag to the end of your RewriteRule to remove (Discard) the Query String. If you're using 2.2 or earlier, the [QSD] flag isn't available. However, that trailing ? doesn't actually hurt anything, and most website users never look at the URL anyway. If you're doing this for imaginary "SEO" benefits, you're almost certainly wasting time for no actual real benefit.

Note also that you don't need to (and shouldn't) escape characters in the target of a RewriteRule. Thus:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?awebsite\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http://www.awebsite.com/bgh"
```

Comment: I should have mentioned, the reason that I'm doing this is because I'm going to be actually changing the URLs in the Drupal backend, and I want to make sure that Google can still follow the old links until it picks up on the new, shorter URLs. 

So you don't think that the trailing ? will make a difference when it comes to indexing the new URLs?